# Regular expression for IR cell phone number

Tags: c#, regex

I am going to validate the IR cell phone number using the regular expression but it does not match it! For example '09126104851'.
What is the problem?

```
"^09[123456789]{2}(^0[123456789]{1}[0-9]{6}|[123456789]{1}[0-9]{7})$"
```

Comment: why do you have `^`, start of the string, at the beginning and in the middle of the regex? how would that ever match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is equivalent to:

```
^09[1-9]{2}(^0[1-9]{1}[0-9]{6}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7})$
```

Which also can be written shorter as:

```
^09[1-9]{2}(^0[1-9]{1}\d{6}|[1-9]{1}\d{7})$
```

Now you've made an error in the middle is `^0`. Probably you wanted `[^0]` ( everything not zero):

```
^09[1-9]{2}([^0][1-9]{1}\d{6}|[1-9]{1}\d{7})$
```

But the biggest problem is this part:

- `09[1-9]{2}` matches in total 4 digits
- `[^0][1-9]{1}\d{6}`matches in total 8 digits
- `[1-9]{1}\d{7}` matches also 8 digits in total

So you are trying to match 8+4=12 digits while phone number has 11.

I bet you wanted expression to be:

```
^09[1-9]{2}([1-9]{1}\d{6}|[1-9]{1}\d{6})$
```

And now you will notice that alternating matches before and after `|` are
the same ! So this makes expression even smaller:

```
^09[1-9]{2}([1-9]{1}\d{6})$
```

If we can dismiss grouping of last 7 digits - we will notice similar parts:
`[1-9]{2}` and `[1-9]{1}`. This lets to reduce expression further:

```
^09[1-9]{3}\d{6}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3vgFw7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Because You have `^` symbol in the middle of regular expression. 
`^` means "in the start of the string".
You need regex from @msd : `^09\d{9}$`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression instead: `"^09\d{9}$"`

For example:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch("09126104851", @"^09\d{9}$")
```

Check it on fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8quyvL